# Get a list of all artists from Soundcloud

Tags: api, soundcloud

Is there any way of getting a list of all artists who are presented on Soundcloud ( via it`s API or by some other means) ?

Comment: Have you tried to come up with / researched anything?

Comment: Hello, I`m not sure what do you mean by '/'. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit of code which should point you in the right direction. 
Problem could be the response limit, which is 200.

That's why you have to store the responses anywhere to get a full list of all artists (users) on SC.

To get a list of users you can do the following by using the SC JS SDK.
May be you can play around with the q parameter.

JS Code:

```
SC.initialize({ client_id: "201b55a1a16e7c0a122d112590b32e4a"});
SC.get('/users', { limit: 200}, function(users) { console.log(users);});
```

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/9kUwq/

Docs:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users

Comment: If I understand you right: I virtually need to get a list of all users, then to get all their tracks, then to parse each track title in order to extract artist name, don`t I?

Comment: @nickf4 Yeah, I`m aware of that. I just need to search for new artists ( those who are not stored in my db) and add them to my artists db. So the more new artists I get - the better. Regretfully, it seems that even if I could traverse roughly through every user, I would fail because it is impossible to tell artist name from song name in track title ( as concluded here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054970/soundcloud-api-pull-artist-name-and-song-title-separately) )

Comment: Its up to you. I dont know what your program will look like, but as far as i know you have to build your own artist db. How you check if there are new artists, thats is up to you. 

You can use get/users endpoint or search for latest uploaded tracks and then check if this particular user is already in your db - or not.

And sure you will get the user from the track-id. But as stated in the link, sometimes a label, promoter uploads an track using their account. 

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks